# Standard method for printing long description of class in Python

Tags: python, pretty-print

I have a Python class `ElectionData` that stores all data for an election, including a list of `ElectionRound` instances that in turn store the vote counts for each round.

For debugging and verbose printing purposes, I would like an option to fully print all of the data within `ElectionData`, including the vote counts in each contained `ElectionRound`. This printout should be human-readable, formatting the information with newlines.

My understanding is that `__repr__()` is for an unambiguous system representation of the instance and `__str()__` is for a more concise user representation, but I am not sure if it is meant for large representations.

Given that this "pretty" formatted printout could be quite long, is using `__str()__` still advised, or should I create a new method like `description()` for this purpose?

**Edit:**

I have already researched the difference between `__str__()` and `__repr__()`; this question is about if a long-form printout should use `__str__()` or a separate method

Comment: `__str__` should be concise (one line).  Define a new method, called `tabulate` or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_\_str\_\_ and \_\_repr\_\_ in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: I'd go with writing your own `description()` method

Comment: You can invert the control: instead calling a method like `instance.fancy_print()`, you can define a function and use it: `fancy_print(instance)`. This allows you to put more logic into the function and less into the instance method(s) it calls, and use a short alias for it in your REPL (`p = fancy_print; p(x)`) without making compromises between descriptiveness and conciseness in naming your instance methods.